# Transform a sum of Likert items to normality

Tags: data-transformation, likert, normality-assumption

I am analysing data from a survey. There are 11 items, each to be answered on a 5 point Likert scale. It seems reasonable to summarize the results by taking their average, which can then be the response in a mixed effects model.

There are 1679 subjects and 91 distinct values in the measure score.

[image: Histogram of the measure score]

So basically, the outcome can be treated as continuous, but it is not normal. A number of people answered 5 to each item (thus getting a "perfect" score of 5) and one individual answered 1 to each item. I would like to transform the data to something a bit more normalesque, or use an appropriate distribution in a generalized linear model. However, I'm not sure what's best. I can't simply rescale and use a sigmoid transformation, since I have values at the endpoints. What do people usually do in this situation? Pretend the data are normal and carry on?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to transform the response based on its distribution?  Usually you would only be concerned about the distribution of its residuals in your model.

Comment: Yes, good point. But my residuals are not going to be normal either, whatever the model, since they are bounded above at 5.

Comment: That's right: a transformation to normality is hopeless.  But in many circumstances that would be unnecessary.  Of greater importance is to achieve approximately symmetrical residuals with few outliers.  That is something that could be achieved. If you want, you could treat at 1's and 5's as (left) and (right) censored values, too.

Comment: "A number of people answered 5 to each item (thus getting a "perfect" score of 5)" appears to contradict "the outcome can be treated as continuous"

Comment: @Glen_b The decision to model the data as continuous could be both insightful and economical. One reasonable interpretation is that some people found the high end of the scale to be truncated, so the data could be viewed as a censored version of a continuous variable--which has been measured to only about 1.7 significant digits of precision. Mere imprecision ought not to be the chief determiner of whether data should be modeled with continuous or discrete distributions. I would be a bit more concerned about sensitivities to the weights used in combining the 11 answers, among other things.

Comment: @whuber A *decision* to treat it that way may indeed be both the things you say, especially if it's treated as a censored continuous variable. I'm not at all opposed to making deliberate modelling choices along those lines. But that's not how I read the sentence, which seemed to treat "continuity" as a conclusion (rather than a deliberate decision) resulting from some feature of the data, while describing something else that seemed to contradict the conclusion. I'd like the situation to be clearly recognized (a bunch of values at 5 is not "continuous") because *then* it's possible to ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... come to a sensible modelling decision (such as to say "if we treat it as censored at 5, we can reasonably treat it as censored continuous data"). There's an important difference between a deliberate modelling choice that recognizes the issue and deals with it and a conclusion that doesn't seem to even notice it's directly contradicted by an obvious feature of the data. In some cases - perhaps even this one - it might be reasonable to treat the variable as continuous even without the censoring, but done with an eye to consequences, which one might use simulation (say) to investigate.

Comment: I personally find the histogram handsome, and wouldn't bother much. It is only moderately skewed, and most psychometric Likert-sum constructs would show similar distribution. What I would probably do though - is to track down (and throw out) queer response patterns, such as: all items = constant; all items = ultimates (1 5 1 5 5 1)

Comment: These are all interesting suggestions. I hadn't thought of censoring, although it would be difficult to justify from the nature of the study. Health care providers were asked questions about initiatives that they applied never, hardly ever, sometimes, often, always .... that kind of thing. It's hard to imagine that they were longing for a category of "Totally, to the max!" beyond the 5th point. It's the kind of survey where a lot of people are going to check "alwalys,always,always ..." since that's clearly what they SHOULD be doing.

Comment: I "decided" that the data were continuous on the grounds that once you add up a sufficient number of discrete items, nothing but mathematical complexity awaits the analyst who attempts to work with the exact distribution. Perhaps one should have more courage in situations like this.